# How to generate the combinations of an array and divide the numbers in each combination by the product of the numbers in the same combination?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, combinations

Given an array of N size, I want to return all possible permutations of the array. For each permutation of the array I want to return the value of each number in that combination divided by the sum of the other numbers in the combination including the dividend.

Example: Give the array 123, you find all the possible combinations which are (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3). You then take each combination and divide it as such: (1,2) = (1/1+2) = .33333. (2,1) = (2/1+2) = .66666.

```
import math
import itertools
from itertools import combinations
import numpy as np
n = int(input("Enter The Amount of Numbers in the List: ")
)
z = []
q = []
for i in range(0,n):
  x = float(input("Enter the numbers: "))
  q.append(x)
h = n+1

permutation_list = []
for i in range(1, len(q)+1):
    permutations = combinations(q, i)
    for perm in permutations:
        perm_prod = 1
        for j in range(len(perm)):
            perm_prod *= perm[j] 
        for j in range(len(perm)-1):
          for k in range(1,len(perm)):
            prod_without_this = perm[j]+perm[k]
            this_num_div_other_nums = perm[j] / prod_without_this
            second_num = perm[k] / prod_without_this   
            permutation_list.append(this_num_div_other_nums)
            permutation_list.append(second_num)
permutation_list[h:]
print(permutation_list)
```

This is what I have so far but I am having trouble dividing with combinations with length greater than 2. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this, where you loop over each combination for each element in the combo.

```
from itertools import combinations, chain

l = [1,2,3]

c = list(chain.from_iterable([list(combinations(l,i)) for i in range(2,len(l)+1)]))


results = []
for x in c:
    for n in range(len(x)):
        results.append(x[n]/sum(x))
```

Results

```
[0.3333333333333333,
 0.6666666666666666,
 0.25,
 0.75,
 0.4,
 0.6,
 0.16666666666666666,
 0.3333333333333333,
 0.5]
```